# XBMC remote control key repeat

Tags: kodi

Those who have used XBMC with a WiFi remote, such as an Android or iOS device with the official XBMC remote apps, have probably seen this at one time or another:

your remote stops working, when you press a key, that key is repeated very fast.  Sometimes you can break the key repeat loop by pressing that same key again. Sometimes (as this particular morning) you can not.

This problem has existed for literally **years** (it even occurs on the old XBOX only builds) but there seems to be no definite explanation as to what is causing it.   I am asking for a workaround.

(If you Google, you can find threads were [people are ridiculed](http://code.google.com/p/android-xbmcremote/wiki/RemoteKeyRepeat) for bringing up this problem, which is one reason I ask here instead of on the official forums. Also the fact that this problem has persisted for so many years.)

I am running, right now, XBMCBuntu Live Eden and the latest official iOS remote. Although, I have seen this problem on all combinations of remotes and XBMC versions I have tried over the years, which are many. (XBMC on Windows, Linux, OSX, remotes on Android and iOS.)

[Link to bug #136 for the Android remote.](http://code.google.com/p/android-xbmcremote/issues/detail?id=136) It's marked as "fixed" as of client version 636, but the problem is seen again in rev 730. Go figure. There is something fundamentally wrong with how keypresses are sent from the various remotes to XBMC, since this problem is seen across time, XBMC versions and iOS/Android.